# C# Metro serializing a class?

Tags: c#, class, serialization, file-io, microsoft-metro

I was coding a game in C# WPF .NET 4.0 but I've been in the process of porting it to WinRT to be a Metro app.

I can't figure out serialization. Before I would mark a class with [serializable()]
and save it to disk.

So far I've found DataContracts and xmlserialization, but how do I serialize a class and write it to disk?

Do I have to mark every property in the class with an attribute, please help

Answer (score 1):

With `XmlSerializer`, no you don't - in fact, you don't need to mark anything in many cases. Adding attributes allows much more control over the final xml, though.

With `DataContractSerializer`, it is certainly preferred to add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes; you don't get the same type of control, but it works quite well.

The features of the two are different:

- DCS doesn't use constructors - XS uses the public parameterless constructor
- DCS supports serialization callbacks (XS does not)
- XS supports conditional serialization (DCS does not)
- etc

You might also want to consider protobuf-net, which recently supports WinRT, and has smaller output *and* is much faster than the other two (when using the [new precompiler](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html)); it supports pretty much all the features and options from DCS and XS combined, but with fast binary, cross-platform output.

Comment: Can you provide some code as to how to convert a class into a stream? I'm having issues getting this working?

Comment: WinRT XAML Toolkit to the rescue (as usually) - check this for a sample or just get the toolkit and use this and other extension methods that make these things simple: http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17431#309186

Comment: @Windsurfer25 you don't "convert a class into a stream"; you *serialize* an object, writing to a stream. I can write examples of *that* all day long, but frankly it comes down to "look at the most basic example of your chosen serializer".